# iCloud reminders (web site) - missing features?

Tags: icloud, reminders

This Apple KB article implies that one can create new reminders lists, edit details of reminders set as alert time, change folders of reminders, etc.

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12088?locale=en_US

However, I don't see any of these options.  I can add new reminders and edit notes, but I can't do any of the other things it states.

Is the iCloud reminders web interface neutered now?  I don't have the "+ at the top" the article refers to.

As far as I can see, the only things I can do on the iCloud web site are:

- add remidners
- add/modify notes on reminders
- change list colors/appearance
- show/hide completed

I don't think there are any other possible functions - ?

Was hoping to use iCloud on the web as an interim since the macOS desktop reminders app won't sync with iCloud until Catalina.

Here is a screen shot taken on macOS Mojave with Safari 13.0.1...looks the same in the current version of Chrome for macOS as well:

[image]

Comment: My web iCloud [does have that plus](https://i.imgur.com/s5mTBya.png), and when clicked, it indeed creates a new list. All the existing entries have a "Details" link letting you edit the date, list etc. - so the support article seems accurate. Can you post what yours looks like?

Comment: Bizarre - I just added a screen shot to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

This has been like this for a year now. You can't edit the the details of a reminder or even view a URL if attached to the reminder.

This provided information to users so they know it's been like that for awhile and should not expect it to change.